# Working with array of object in Zabbix

Tags: zabbix, json

My HTTP agent on Zabbix recieve data representing count of client's orders:

```
{
  "orders": [
    {
      "client_id": 1,
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "client_id": 2,
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "client_id": 3,
      "count": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

How to create items and then graph of orders count for each client? I know about JSONPath and catching certain fields from JSON, but I can't understand how to work with key:value data.

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating main iteam which stores hole JSON and creating multiple dependent items to store individual values using correct preprocessing.